# Cómo limitar el tamaño de los archivos que pueden subir por FTP mis usuarios?

Tags: php, html, mysql, archivo, ftp

OK tengo un Formulario que sube por medio de php y ftp un archivo a mi servidor, el detalle es que necesito limitar el tamaño de los archivos que suben mis usuario, no deben exceder mas de 1Mb de tamaño, intente algo que encontre por la red y medio lo ajuste a mi codigo, pero no me funciono, supongo que porque no es la sintaxis correcta, alguien podria asesorarme sobre que estoy haciendo mal

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["Cargar"]))

$local =  str_replace(" ", "_", $_FILES['documento']['tmp_name']);
```

segun yo aqui recogo el tamaño del archivo pero aparentemente y le pongo la condicion para que no continue el proceso si pesa mas  pero definitivamente no lo hace, supongo que por aqui esta la falla

```
$tamano = $_FILES['documento']['size']; 

if($tamano > 1100000)
{
echo "Tu archivo no puede ser mayor a 1 MB, intenta de nuevo por favor";
}
```

se supone que si no cumple la condicion entonces continua con esta parte del proceso de subir el archivo

```
else
{

$prefijo = substr(md5(uniqid(rand())),0,3);

$remoto = $prefijo."_".str_replace(" ", "_", $_FILES['documento']['name']);

$id_ftp = ftp_connect("ftp.miservidor.com");

ftp_login ($id_ftp, "miusuario", "micontraseña");

ftp_pasv ($id_ftp, false); 
 
ftp_chdir ($id_ftp, "//public_html/ARMYSOFT/Lost-Ark"); 

$sonrisa=ftp_put($id_ftp,$remoto,$local,FTP_BINARY);

$nametotal=$username.' '.$userlastname;
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
$fechita= date("Y/m/d H:i:s");

$campomarte= $_REQUEST['campoupdate'];

$AMLO= $_REQUEST['chalan'];
        
$query = "UPDATE doctos_empleados SET 

$campomarte ='$remoto'
                                         
WHERE

doctos_empleados.idemp='$AMLO'"
    
;

mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die('La consulta fallo '.mysqli_error());
         
        ftp_quit($id_ftp);  


<script language="JavaScript">
    
        var variable = "<?php echo $AMLO ?>" ;
        var opcion = alert("Se ha adjuntado el Documento al Expediente en el sistema, continua por favor adjuntando todos los documentos obligatorios para que tu expediente sea validado");
        pagina="subeimg.php?deadpool="+variable;
        document.location = (pagina);
    
</script>
```

espero me puedan ayudar o acesorar sobre este pequeño problema

---

Hola a los 2 pues llegue al punto de hacer solo la pregunta para ver si en verdad me esta validando el detalle pero noup no lo hace este es el codigo

```
 if($_FILES['documento']['size'] > 1000000)
 {  echo "si es mas grande"; }
 else
 { echo "es mas pequeño el archivo";}
```

lo triste del asunto es que sea mas grande o mas pequeño me dice lo mismo.... que "es mas pequeño el archivo".....o sea como hace el diferenciador....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LES COMPARTO QUE EN REALIDAD TODAS LAS OPCIONES FUNCIONABAN, PERO NO OBTENÍA EL RESULTADO DESEADO POR OTRO MOTIVO, LES COMENTO CUAL ERA, AL TENER EN CPANEL DE MI SERVDIOR CONFIGURADO upload_max_filesize CONFIGURADO A 2MB, YO ESTABA PROBANDO CON UN ARCHIVO DE 5MB ENTONCES EN ALGUN MOMENTO LOS DATOS NO REGRESABAN PORQUE EL SERVIDOR NO PERMITÍA EL ARCHIVO DE 5MB PERO OJO, CUANDO INTENTE CON UN ARCHIVO DE 1.5MB SORPRESA LA CONDICION SI FUNCIONABA Y ME DEVOLVIA EL MENSAJE DE QUE ESTABA EXEDIENDO EL TAMAÑO, ENTONCES LO QUE HICE FUE SOLO SUBIR EL TAMAÑO EN upload_max_filesize A 16MB Y PROBLEMA RESUELTO LA CONDICION ANDA A LA PERFECCION LOGICAMENTE SI SUBEN UN ARCHIVO MAYOR A 16MB PUES SUCEDERA LO MISMO PERO PARA ESO AGREGE UN CONDICION QUE CUANDO MIS VARIABLES ESTUVIERAN O ME LAS DEVOLVIERA VACIAS ME MANDARA OTRO MENSAJE ASI CON ESO RESOLVI MI PROBLEMA, DE CUALQUIER FORMA MUCHAS GRACIAS A TODOS

Answer (score 0):

crea un archivo `.htaccess` en tu servidor; en la carpeta root de tu proyecto que identifica el apache.

y luego agrega este contenido:

```
#Remplaza xx con el numero de Megas
php_value upload_max_filesize xxM       #Limita el Tamaño en Megas del archivos subidos.
php_value post_max_size xxM             #Limita el Tamaño en Megas del Dialogo POST entre el servidor y el nabvegador.
```

o mediante php puedes hacer algo asi:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["upload"])) {
    // Get Image Dimension
    $fileinfo = @getimagesize($_FILES["file-input"]["tmp_name"]);
    $width = $fileinfo[0];
    $height = $fileinfo[1];
    
    $allowed_image_extension = array(
        "png",
        "jpg",
        "jpeg"
    );
    
    // Get image file extension
    $file_extension = pathinfo($_FILES["file-input"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    
    // Validate file input to check if is not empty
    if (! file_exists($_FILES["file-input"]["tmp_name"])) {
        $response = array(
            "type" => "error",
            "message" => "Choose image file to upload."
        );
    }    // Validate file input to check if is with valid extension
    else if (! in_array($file_extension, $allowed_image_extension)) {
        $response = array(
            "type" => "error",
            "message" => "Upload valiid images. Only PNG and JPEG are allowed."
        );
        echo $result;
    }    // Validate image file size
    else if (($_FILES["file-input"]["size"] > 2000000)) {
        $response = array(
            "type" => "error",
            "message" => "Image size exceeds 2MB"
        );
    }    // Validate image file dimension
    else if ($width > "300" || $height > "200") {
        $response = array(
            "type" => "error",
            "message" => "Image dimension should be within 300X200"
        );
    } else {
        $target = "image/" . basename($_FILES["file-input"]["name"]);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file-input"]["tmp_name"], $target)) {
            $response = array(
                "type" => "success",
                "message" => "Image uploaded successfully."
            );
        } else {
            $response = array(
                "type" => "error",
                "message" => "Problem in uploading image files."
            );
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ok eso lo puedo delimitar incluzo desde cpanel en el area de version de php, la intension aqui es que si el usuario selecciona un archivo mayor  1mb, cuando ejecute el php, obtenga el tamaño del archivo y si es mayor a 1mb, le mande como una alert o un mensaje al usuario de que ese archivo no lo puede subir porque exede el tamaño, para que el usuario seleccione el archivo con el tamaño correcto, ahora bien si selecciona el archivo con el tamaño autorizado o correcto entonces que si le permita subirlo y actualizar mi tabla

Comment: ahora lo dices... debiste agregarlo a tu publicación como lo que esperas que sucede. lamentablemente no somos adivinos..

Comment: @JonathanReyes hay te deje el script que yo uso. saludos.

Comment: ok dejame ajustar parte de tu script al mio y te cuento en un momento como me fue

Comment: Hola @JonathanReyes cuando tratas de subir el archivo en files se pasa un código de error asociado a los límites impuestos por .htaccess . Si el error es por size puedes leerlo (en core de php se define la constante `UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE = 2`) de modo que puedes validar así: `if($_FILES['documento']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE){ //avisar al usuario }else{ //guardar y registrar archivo }` De esa forma puedes aprovechar la respuesta que ofrecida aquí. Ojo debes ver que el código de error no dispare otra alarma

Comment: hola @FranciscoNúñez intente ajustando con tu codigo pero no lo he logrado, intentare con el ejempl que nos deja quevedo

Comment: intenta hacer un `var_dump` de los datos en `$_FILE` y lo colocas en tu pregunta.

Comment: Ojo: Sólo debes tratar de guardar si el código de error es 0 `UPLOAD_ERR_OK = 0` Y, sugiero que hagas validación previa de tipos mime y que no hayan dobles extensiones que camuflan archivos maliciosos

Comment: quiero morir.... llegue al punto en el que estoy intentando esto porque no logro que haga la pregunta....

Comment: if($_FILES['documento']['size'] > 1000000)
        {  echo "si es mas grande"; }
        else
        { echo "es mas pequeño el archivo";}

Comment: pero no funciona morire.... triste y desolado...